# How to display different value of input than ngModel

Tags: angular

I have an input field like this: 
`<input myCurrencyFormatter type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" name="value">`

The input value should be formatted to number such as: 1 024,50(this value should be only visible for input), but value in the ngModel should be stay not formated: 1024.05(dot instead a comma). How I can do it? This is my directive and pipe: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6smqvf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
I don't know how I can input comma and save to model dot.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by redefining getter and setter like so:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="displayValue" >
```

And in ts side:

```
get displayValue(){ return this.realValue + '$' ; }
set displayValue(v){ this.realValue = v?.replace('$',''); }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several approaches. One solution is to use a custom property where you save the converted input to. Listen to input changes with `(change)` and do the conversions there. Find an example below:

In the template:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="test(value)">
  <input myCurrencyFormatter type="text" [ngModel]="value" 
     (change)="storeMyValue($event)"
     name="value">
  <button type="submit">Wtślij</button>
</form>
Custom value: {{ myCustomValue }}
```

And in the component:

```
myCustomValue: string;

public storeMyValue(event) {
   // the following replacements are not very sophisticated, but they
   // show the idea
   this.myCustomValue = event.target.value.trim().replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(",",".");
}
```

If you want to re-use this, you might want to consider to write a custom component for that case.

Comment: I need display this value in this input field and in this way [ngModel]="value" don't update and I send to server the unchanged object data I have a few input field and i have model docum with property such as docum.price, docum.amount.

Comment: You shouldn't bind the model property that is sent to the backend in the input field. The property used in `[ngModel]` should live only temporarily within in your component.  In the `change` method do something like `this.docum.price = event.target.value...."

Comment: Actually I use ng2-currency-mask, but in this directive number start typing  to the left of  the decimal place for example If I type 10 it will be  0,10 instead of 10,00. I need to change this design and I try write own directive and I don't know how i can accomplish it.

Comment: I think manually unmask each input element, which is not a great option.

Comment: True, if you have multiple occurrences of that requirement, you'd be better off with a custom component. Then you can use `[(ngModel)]` without change as you used to.

Answer (score 0):

OnFocus remove separator and restore it on focusout

```
@HostListener('focus')
  onFocus() {
    let element = this.el.nativeElement;

    // Remove separator
    element.value = element.value.toString().replace(this.separator, '');
  }

  @HostListener('focusout')
  onFocusLost() {
    let element = this.el.nativeElement;

    // Add separator
    if (+element.value > 999) {
      element.value = element.value.replace('/^\d+/g', '').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, this.separator);
    }
```

}